# How to make two select forms of different ids and names return their ids using $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form with two select dropdown lists. Each one has the same sites that you leave from/go to. I'm trying to grab the ID of each one and store them as separate variables, but each time I select a new option, the variables reset to `undefined`. My code looks like this:

```
$('select[name=Depart], select[name=Return]').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var depart_id;
    var return_id;

    // Grabs the place you left from
    var dep = $('select[name=Depart] option:selected').val(); 

    // Grabs the place you traveled to
    var ret = $('select[name=Return] option:selected').val();

    // Grabs the day in the log as a string 
    var day_id_raw = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 

    // Creates a jQuery object from the string above
    var day_id = $('#' + day_id_raw);

    // Creates a substring of the string above cutting it off at the day number in the log. E.g. "Day 1" in the log becomes the number "1". 
    var day_num = day_id_raw.substring(3, day_id_raw.length); 

    //Creates a jQuery object for the miles of the day table column
    var miles_today = $('#miles_day' + day_num);

    if($(this).is($('select[name=Depart]'))){
        depart_id = id;
    }
    if($(this).is($('select[name=Return]'))){
        return_id = id; 
    }

    // Checks if the place you left from contains a column to output how many miles you traveled that day. 
    if(day_id.has(miles_today)){
        miles_today.text(depart_id + "\n" + return_id);
    }
)};
```

The last `if` statement is just for debugging purposes. `miles_today` is a blank div that I'm writing content to in order to test if the variables are actually working. Like I said earlier, each time I change an option on either select input, the alternate variable is cleared. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry for the late reply and ambiguous wording. Here is a working example of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/8xVuX/2/ 
Just enter 1 or 2 in the 'Number of days' field and it should add a new row. If you click the select menu for 'Departed From' and choose an option, it'll output its `id` in the field to the left, but undefined for the other field 'Returned To's `id`. I want to have both `id`s displayed when the select options are changed.

Comment: You wanted to declare `depart_id` and `return_id` outside of the change handler? Or what do you mean by "reset to undefined"?

Answer (score 2):

Get them outside the change function, and use them wherever you'd like :

```
var depart_id = $('select[name=Depart]').prop('id'),
    return_id = $('select[name=Return]').prop('id');

$('select[name=Depart], select[name=Return]').on('change', function(){

    miles_today.text(depart_id + "\n" + return_id);

});
```

but are you sure you should'nt be getting the value ?

Comment: @Bergi - do you really need to update the ID, it's not very likely to change ?

Comment: Uh, no, I somehow got the idea that OP wants those variables changing based on the current selections. Or maybe he had more than one select with the same name, but different ids… But yes, probably doesn't make much sense. GN8 :-)